# django manager with limit

Tags: django, django-managers

recentes.html

```
{% regroup galeria by subcategoria as galeria_list %}
{% for galeria in galeria_list %}

        <p>{{ galeria.grouper.titulo_pt }}</p>
        <div class="workSeriesThumbnailStrip">

        {% for item in galeria.list %}
        <a href="/galeria/{{ item.subcategoria }}/" title="{{ item.subcategoria }}">
            <img src="{{ item.thumbnail_url }}" border="0" alt="" />
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Subcategoria(models.Model):

    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria)
    imagem_de_capa = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/capa/', null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Galeria(models.Model):
    subcategoria = models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria)
```

views.py

```
def recents_pt(request):
    galeria = Galeria.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(

        'recentes.html',

        locals(),

        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have some classes in my model. 
I'm using regroup in a template to organize the galleries through the subcategories.

I need to limit the number of subcategories in 5
Slice in template don't work,  since it limits the gallery. Any idea?

Thought about doing a Manager, like a:

```
class SubCategoriaFiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(SubCategoriaFiveManager, self).get_query_set()
```

But the manager don't support a [:5] - limit to 5
How i can proceeed?

Answer (score 0):

Querysets do support slicing. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets